# Adding total of scores on Google form

Tags: forms, evaluation, add-on

How can I get the total of the 1s, 2s, 3s and 4s at the end of the Google form as total? Like when I am evaluating an employee's performance, I need to see the total of the 1s, 2s, 3s and 4s that I have selected so that I can choose a suitable overall grade.

I tried using Neartail add-on but this helps only if the numbers are written with a currency sign.